# grep if the next X lines doesn't contain a specific string

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I created a cron job that runs every few minutes and performs "grep" on a log file in order to find warnings.
I'd like to ignore a warning which containing a specific string after 6 lines from the beginning of the relevant warning.
The challenge is since each warning consists of several separate lines rather than one long line.
Is there any recommended way to do that?

Log for example:

```
2018-04-04 05:15:13,576 [housekeeper] DEBUG not-relevant...
2018-04-04 05:16:19,226 [housekeeper] DEBUG not-relevant...
2018-04-04 05:45:28,383 [housekeeper] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyLeakTask - Connection leak detection triggered for com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@2f350071, stack trace follows
java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
    at com.sql.HikariConnectionPool.getConnection(java:)
    at com.DBConnection.getConn(java:)
    at com.DBConnection.getConn(java:)
    at com.EAgent.checkER(aaa.java:)
    at com.EAgent$EExecuter.run(aaa.java:)
2018-04-04 05:55:54,425 [housekeeper] DEBUG not-relevant...
2018-04-04 05:58:16,814 [DBPool housekeeper] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyLeakTask - Connection leak detection triggered for com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@45df031, stack trace follows
java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
    at com.HikariConnectionPool.getConnection(HikariConnectionPool.java:)
    at com.DBConnection.getConn(aaa.java:)
    at com.DBConnection.getConn(aaa.java:)
    at com.m.checkUC(aaa.java:)
    at com.m.run(aaa.java:)
    at java.c.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(aaa.java:)
    at java.c.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(aaa.java:)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(aaa.java:)
```

My grep:`grep -A6 -ne 'Connection leak detection' -ne WARN myfile.log`

I want to ignore all the warnings which containing "EAgent", so that the output will be:

```
2018-04-04 05:58:16,814 [DBPool housekeeper] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyLeakTask - Connection leak detection triggered for com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@45df031, stack trace follows
java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
    at com.HikariConnectionPool.getConnection(HikariConnectionPool.java:)
    at com.DBConnection.getConn(aaa.java:)
    at com.DBConnection.getConn(aaa.java:)
    at com.m.checkUC(aaa.java:)
    at com.m.run(aaa.java:)
    at java.c.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(aaa.java:)
    at java.c.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(aaa.java:)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(aaa.java:)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add apart from error lines by which logic we should remove other lines?

Comment: Hi. All the stack trace need to be removed, from the "WARN" line (from the date) till the end of the relevant stack trace. in my case my grep should return only the WARN without the "EAgent" as I wrote.

Comment: Kindly try my code and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: Works great! in order to retreive all the WRRN exept the EAgent I used awk '/^[0-9]+/{if(val && !non_flag){print val};non_flag=val=""} /EAgent/ || /DEBUG/{non_flag=1} {val=val?val ORS $0:$0} END{if(val && !non_flag){print val}}' myfile.log       Thanks

Comment: Cool, glad that it worked for you, cheers and happy learning :)

Comment: Now I just have to understand your magical code, can you explain or just provide me pls link to a good tutorial? Many thanks.

Comment: I personally learnt scripting and awk from forums and practice only, you could check on tutorial points may be and you could get lot of learning stuff on SO too, for my code give me few mins will add explanation of it too in few mins.

Comment: I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Sure, added explanation to code now too, cheers happy learning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[0-9]/ { prt() }
{ rec = rec $0 ORS }
END { prt() }
function prt() {
    if ( (rec ~ /WARN/) && (rec !~ /EAgent/) ) {
        printf "%s", rec
    }
    rec = ""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
2018-04-04 05:58:16,814 [DBPool housekeeper] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyLeakTask - Connection leak detection triggered for com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@45df031, stack trace follows
java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
    at com.HikariConnectionPool.getConnection(HikariConnectionPool.java:)
    at com.DBConnection.getConn(aaa.java:)
    at com.DBConnection.getConn(aaa.java:)
    at com.m.checkUC(aaa.java:)
    at com.m.run(aaa.java:)
    at java.c.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(aaa.java:)
    at java.c.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(aaa.java:)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(aaa.java:)
```

If speed of execution is an issue, this should be slightly faster:

```
/^[0-9]/ {
    if (inWarn) {
        prt()
    }
    inWarn = /WARN/
}
inWarn { rec = rec $0 ORS }
END { if (inWarn) prt() }
function prt() {
    if ( rec !~ /EAgent/ ) {
        printf "%s", rec
    }
    rec = ""
}
```

Comment: +1 but I would optimized it in such a way: `/^[0-9].+ WARN/ { prt() }` - to avoid calling `prt()` and further matching of `rec ~ /WARN/` on each non-`WARN` log line (there are many of those). Then, in `prt()` function: `if(rec && rec !~ /EAgent/)`

Comment: I can't do that exactly as the WARN is part of the previous block, not necessarily the current line, and could be present in either, both or neither. Then I'd also have to add the external test for WARN to the END section too and `rec` could get huge if there's, say, thousands of lines between each WARN (or add more code to handle that too). IMHO the small overhead of an unnecessary function call is worth the trade-off compared to duplicate and more complex code. General rule - don't optimize for performance until if/when it proves necessary.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest just for comparison, I added at the end what the code would have to look like to avoid calling prt() for non-WARN blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you?

```
awk '/^[0-9]+/{if(val && !non_flag){print val};non_flag=val=""} /EAgent/ || /DEBUG not-relevant/{non_flag=1} {val=val?val ORS $0:$0} END{if(val && !non_flag){print val}}' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too here.

```
awk '
/^[0-9]+/{
   if(val && !non_flag){
      print val};
   non_flag=val=""}
/EAgent/ || /DEBUG not-relevant/{
   non_flag=1}
{
   val=val?val ORS $0:$0
}
END{
   if(val && !non_flag){
      print val}
}
'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '
/^[0-9]+/{                          ##Checking condition here if a line starts with digits then do following.
   if(val && !non_flag){            ##Checking if variable val is NOT NULL and variable non_flag is NULL then do following.
      print val};                   ##Printing variable val here.
   non_flag=val=""}                 ##Nullifying the value of variable non_flag and val here.
/EAgent/ || /DEBUG not-relevant/{   ##Searching for strings EAgent OR DEBUG not-relevent in a line if either of them found do following
   non_flag=1}                      ##Set variable non_flag value to 1 here.
{
   val=val?val ORS $0:$0            ##Creating variable val whose value is current line and it concatenates its own value with it.
}
END{                                ##Starting END block of awk here.
   if(val && !non_flag){            ##Checking condition if variable val is NOT NULL and variable non_flag is NULL then do following.
      print val}                    ##Printing the variable val here.
}
'   Input_file                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Can you please simplify an awk as follows:
1. Line starts with digits
2. Contains: "Timeout failure" or "Connection leak detection" or "WARN"
3. Does not contain EAgent (exclude)

In this way, there will be no need to add INFO and DEBUG and other irrelevant log lines to the formula. 
(Only what we need, not what we do not need ...)

Thanks

Comment: @Haimon, kindly open a new thread for it, as 1 thread 1 question only should be there :)

Comment: Created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710442/awk-searching-for-string-if-next-x-lines-doesnt-contain-a-specific-string  :)