# awk searching for string if next X lines doesn't contain a specific string

Tags: awk

Following my previous question [grep if the next X lines doesn't contain a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49657736/grep-if-the-next-x-lines-doesnt-contain-a-specific-string)
I'd like to get help in order to make the awk more simple.

Given the following log:

```
2018-04-04 04:37:41,916 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - autoCommit......................true
    2018-04-04 04:37:41,916 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - catalog.........................null
    2018-04-04 04:37:41,916 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionInitSql...............null
    2018-04-04 04:37:41,916 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionTestQuery.............null
    2018-04-04 04:48:43,209 [housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - Before cleanup  stats (total=13, active=2, idle=11, waiting=0)
    2018-04-04 05:16:19,226 [housekeeper] DEBUG not-relevant...
    2018-04-04 05:45:28,383 [housekeeper] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyLeakTask - Connection leak detection triggered for com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@2f350071, stack trace follows
    java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
        at com.sql.HikariConnectionPool.getConnection(java:)
        at com.DBConnection.getConn(java:)
        at com.DBConnection.getConn(java:)
        at com.EAgent.checkER(aaa.java:)
        at com.EAgent$EExecuter.run(aaa.java:)
    2018-04-04 05:55:54,425 [housekeeper] DEBUG not-relevant...
2018-04-04 04:48:13,208 [housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=13, active=0, idle=13, waiting=0)
2018-04-04 04:48:13,208 [housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=13, active=0, idle=13, waiting=0)
    2018-04-04 05:58:16,814 [DBPool housekeeper] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyLeakTask - Connection leak detection triggered for com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@45df031, stack trace follows
    java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
        at com.HikariConnectionPool.getConnection(HikariConnectionPool.java:)
        at com.DBConnection.getConn(aaa.java:)
        at com.DBConnection.getConn(aaa.java:)
        at com.m.checkUC(aaa.java:)
        at com.m.run(aaa.java:)
        at java.c.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(aaa.java:)
        at java.c.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(aaa.java:)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(aaa.java:)
    2018-04-04 04:37:41,921 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - Started.
    2018-04-04 04:49:43,209 [housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=11, active=0, idle=11, waiting=0)
    2018-04-04 04:49:43,209 [housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=11, active=0, idle=11, waiting=0)
```

I'd like an awk code that filter by the following conditions:
1. Line starts with digits.
2. Contains: "Timeout failure" or "Connection leak detection" or "WARN"
3. Does not contain EAgent (exclude - even if contains WARN or other term from #2)

In this way, there will be no need to add INFO and DEBUG and other irrelevant log lines to the formula - it will be ignored automatically.
(Search only what we need, not what we do not need ...)

The output should presents only the second WARN stack-trace without the "EAgent":

```
        2018-04-04 05:58:16,814 [DBPool housekeeper] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyLeakTask - Connection leak detection triggered for com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@45df031, stack trace follows
    java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
        at com.HikariConnectionPool.getConnection(HikariConnectionPool.java:)
        at com.DBConnection.getConn(aaa.java:)
        at com.DBConnection.getConn(aaa.java:)
        at com.m.checkUC(aaa.java:)
        at com.m.run(aaa.java:)
        at java.c.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(aaa.java:)
        at java.c.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(aaa.java:)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(aaa.java:)
```

Thanks

Comment: Best I can tell [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49658459/1745001) already does exactly what you're asking for now too. If not and it's not obvious how to tweak it to do what you want then since you've already accepted an answer to this question post a new question explaining what it is you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{line=$0;gsub(/^ +/,"")} /^[0-9]+/{flag=""} /^[0-9]+/ && (/WARN/ || /Timeout failure/ || /Connection leak detection/){flag=1;if(val && val !~ /EAgent/){print val};val=""}  flag{val=val?val ORS line:line} END{if(val){print val}}' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
{
  line=$0;
  gsub(/^ +/,"")
}
/^[0-9]+/{
  flag=""}
/^[0-9]+/ && (/WARN/ || /Timeout failure/ || /Connection leak detection/){
  flag=1;
  if(val && val !~ /EAgent/){
    print val};
  val=""
}
flag{
  val=val?val ORS line:line}
END{
  if(val){
    print val}
}'   Input_file
```

---

---

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation of code too now for understanding and learning for all.

```
awk '
{
  line=$0;                                                                ##Creating variable named line which will have current line value in it.
  gsub(/^ +/,"")                                                          ##using gsub for removing initial space from each line to match.
}
/^[0-9]+/{                                                                ##Checking condition if a line starts with digits then do following.
  flag=""}                                                                ##Nullifying variable flag here.
/^[0-9]+/ && (/WARN/ || /Timeout failure/ || /Connection leak detection/){##Checking if a line starting from 0 to 9 and having either WARN, timeout or leak ones.
  flag=1;                                                                 ##Setting variable named flag value as 1 here.
  if(val && val !~ /EAgent/){                                             ##Checking condition if variable val is NOT NULL and val NOT having string EAgent do follows.
     print val};                                                          ##Printing variable named val here.
  val=""}                                                                 ##Nullifying variable val here.
  flag{                                                                   ##Checking condition if variable flag is NOT NULL here then do following.
     val=val?val ORS line:line}                                           ##Creating variable vale and concatenating its value with own value or have line variable in.
END{                                                                      ##Staring END section of awk code here now.
  if(val){                                                                ##Checking if variable val value is NOT NULL then do following.
     print val}                                                           ##Printing the variable val value here.
}' Input_file                                                    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't filtered the results - all the WARN returned. the only change is that the first line is missed in all WARNs with this awk. (i.e without the digits line, started from: java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected...)

Comment: @Haimon, thought that you want to only leave `WARN` lines, please add expected output in your post I will fix it then. Let me know once you edit your post with expected output then.

Comment: Already wrote: "The output should presents only the second WARN stack-trace without the "EAgent". - All the stack of the other WARNs should be presented except for the one with EAgent.. Please LMK if something is not cleat.

Comment: @Haimon, it will be better if you could add expected output in your post it will be more clear then, please do so.

Comment: @Haimon, please check my edited solution and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: Works fine but as I mentioned in #2 sometimes there's no WARN in the block but only "Timeout failure" or "Connection leak detection" can you add "or" in the awk pls?

Comment: @Haimon, Done, kindly check and let me know in case of queries?

Comment: @Haimon, your welcome, glad that it helped you, will add explanation too in my code. keep learning and keep sharing knowledge on SO.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and knowledge sharing.

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13, I found an issue with this awk script. when there is only one WARN in the Input_file, and this WARN contain the "EAgent", the WARN returns in the output - (while this case supposed to return nothing). 
filter works fine only if there are more than one and different WARNs.

Comment: Again, see [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49658459/1745001). You really need to think through the logic of the answers you're considering to make sure they do what you want rather than just accepting the first one you get that produces the expected output from some specific sample input you provided. And if you can't follow the logic then that alone should be worth your consideration!

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you sir. Haimon, I tried to get the complete question and tried to help, kindly go through Ed sir's answer once. Keep Learning !!

Comment: @EdMorton, I tried my best to give answer to OP, since all requirements were not given together so missed it. I hope OP gets from your previous answer and we should be good here.

Comment: Ravinder - right, all we have to go by is what the OP shares with us. After that it's up to them....